# C# DataGridView Column custom ValueType

Tags: c#, datagridview, value-type

I have a simple `DataGridView`, and a custom type `MyType`, which looks like this:

```
class MyType
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public MyType(string Prop1 = "Empty", int Prop2 = 0)
    {
        this.Prop1 = Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = Prop2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Prop1 + "[" + this.Prop2 + "]";
    }
}
```

I want to add a column to the `DataGridView` of type `MyType` that can show `Prop1` for example. I do something like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridViewColumn c1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "C1" };
DataGridViewColumn c2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "C2" };
DataGridViewColumn c3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    Name = "C3",
    ValueType = typeof(MyType),
    DataPropertyName = "Prop1"
};
DataGridViewColumn c4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "C4" };
this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

And when I use the `DataGridView` (column "C3" of course), it can't convert the string value in the cell, which I typed, to my custom type `MyType` (obviously I need to provide some kind of conversion-ability). I am unsure how to do this, nor can I find a decent example on how it is done. Also I am trying to avoid setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` to anything if possible. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: I guess you should be looking for something like [CellParsing event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AndrewK Yeah it could be a good workaround for what I need. Thanks :)

Comment: I have to ask… why are you trying to avoid a `DataSource`? Using a `DataSource`, is usually a better approach on many levels and reduces the amount of work for you.

Comment: I can recommend a tutorial that describes how to make a `DateTime` `DataGridViewColumn`. [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells). I am guessing (with some effort) that you could adapt this to your class.

Comment: If you did implement a “MyType” column or use the “MyType” class another way, IMHO the biggest hurdle is the realization that YOU will have to implement many methods to address how the user “edits” the “MyType” cells. Currently, if you type ANYTHING into one of the “MyType” cells… the grid will throw an endless `DataError` when exiting the cell because those methods have not been implemented. Since “MyType” has multiple properties, I am guessing this is going to be a challenge for both you and the user. I am curious why you could not simply add a column for the “Prop2” property.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks :) However DataSource brings you constraints like handling SortCompare event (ok I don't need it really), but also it causes me to lose Cell Styles like BackColor every time i sort a column (ok I did manage to handle that as well), however, setting the DataSource made some other things more redundant and a little less efficient, not really a big deal but as I said, if possible w/o it. Anyway, the app works with a database, and for instance, in that database (SQL) i want to store the backcolor of the cell as well. You can see why I can't have another column for the property. :)

Comment: @JohnG Anyway as AndrewK suggested I just implemented the CellParsing event, and mearly converted the string to `MyType`, if the CellValueType is of that or some subtype.. It wasn't much of a deal, basically bunch of if's to check if I can make a conversion, and if I can, I set the `e.ParsingApplied` to true so that the parsing won't go on and throw the error (and of course I parse it), else I don't need to parse it to my type and I leave it be, all done in 5 lines of code actually :)